# angular2 and iter over hash in array

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an json object that looks like this.

```
models = [{
    "mid_704a2eb91eb54299bb3cc4487bf14557": {
        "data": {},
        "name": "uberme"
    },
    "mid_8ccd9a1340b54e76915c690b46eb996a": {
        "data": {},
        "name": "test"
    }
}]
```

In my template, how do I iterate so table looks like this:

```
uberme mid_704a2eb91eb54299bb3cc4487bf14557
test  mid_8ccd9a1340b54e76915c690b46eb996a
```

I only know how to do the below but did not work;

```
      <tr *ngFor="let model of models">
      {{ model | json}}
      <td>{{ model.name }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those property names (such as `mid_704a2eb91eb54299bb3cc4487bf14557`) aren't fixed and known beforehand for you to use them, so you need to use `Object.keys()` to get their value.

So when the `models` is:

```
models = [{
    "mid_704a2eb91eb54299bb3cc4487bf14557": {
        "data": {},
        "name": "uberme"
    },
    "mid_8ccd9a1340b54e76915c690b46eb996a": {
        "data": {},
        "name": "test"
    }
}]
```

Then `Object.keys(models[0])` returns `['mid_704a2eb91eb54299bb3cc4487bf14557', 'mid_8ccd9a1340b54e76915c690b46eb996a']`.

That way, if the object always keeps that structure, you could use something like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(models[0])">
    <td>{{ models[0][key].name }}  {{ key }}</td>
```